# Listview with image icon

Tags: android, android-listview

I am working on an app and I want to display an image beside text in a `Listview`. 
My list view is populate by an array adapter and the icon placed beside the text will be the same for every item. I've read around and I have found that I should use a custom adapter and I am new to the android so can anyone give me reference or help me out?

Comment: Google it you'll get faster response.

Comment: You can use a custom adapter to import your listview with a custom XML file call inside your application. I use it extensively in my app. If you need to know more let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html

General steps.

1. Create custom object
2. Create ArrayAdapter of this custom object.
3. Override some methods of the Array Adapter. Particularly, the
   `getCount()` where you need to return the size of the list of items.
4. Make sure you implement your logic appropriately in the `getView()` method.
5. Also, you mentioned you are using the same image for all
   the items (mostly you are storing this in your drawable folder and
   will be pretty straight forward) But in case, you load images from
   URL, I would suggest [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Picasso, never heard of it. Great tip!

Comment: @Fabian yeah, it is by Square! Square has been building some awesome libraries for Android. :)